# count number of checked checkboxes in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Hi I am trying to count and printing the number of checked checkboxes while I am checking or unchecking a checkboxes from hbs page.Let me know how to write actions for doing this

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use https://ember-twiddle.com for creating minimum verifiable example